# Charging 72V battery bank from 15VDC source

Tags: dc, dc-motor, dc-dc-converter

Using a constant source I have a DC generator that can produce over 15 volts continually. I have a 72 volt battery bank and another 72v-motor that runs off of that battery bank. How can I best connect this generator to charge the 72-v bank? How well will a 12v to 72 DC-to-DC Converter work with providing constant charging to the battery bank. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

There are solutions to converting lower voltages to higher voltages but none (not surprisingly) are 100% in power conversion effciency.

Lets say you need 2A at 72V to charge your battery pack and run your motor. That's a power of 144W. Add-on 15% of that power to account for inefficiencies in the low voltage conversion and you get a likely input power demand of about 166W.

If your input is 12V then this will need to supply \$\frac{166}{12}\$ amps which is near enough 14A.

> How well will a 12v to 72 DC-to-DC Converter work with providing
>   constant charging to the battery bank

Hopefully you have the methods to calculate whether your 12V source can supply demands. Obviously you plug in your own current (not the 2A I originally said) and redo the calculation.

Comment: Thank you Andy. If possible, I have 2 more scenarios from which I would want to use the most productive. 1. I have a 72V SuperCapacitor Bank which I first wanted to use as the buffer to receive the current from the generator and then to the regular battery bank and simultaneously to the 72v motor; or 2) I have the setup currently from the gen. to the dc-to-dc converter and then to the SuperCap bank then to the battery bank. Which would be much more wiser. I can show you the project, but I would not like it shown here. If you would allow me to ask, please send me and email and I'll respond.

Comment: alexrr60@yahoo.com

Comment: @AlexanderRobles I don't do private consultations, sorry.